# forwardref test coverage w/o using Testbed?

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, ts-jest

We have some custom form control components with decorators like...

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'value-selector',
  templateUrl: './selector.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./selector.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => ValueSelectorComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
```

We had to add the forwardRef when updating some dependencies, mostly babel...if that matters. Our provider changed from:
`useExisting: ValueSelectorComponent,`
to:
`useExisting: forwardRef(() => ValueSelectorComponent),`

The JEST spec tests create a new instance via an instantiate method that the beforeEach runs:

```js
function instantiate({
  eventTypeService = {},
  translationService = {}
}): ValueSelectorComponent {
  return new ValueSelectorComponent(
    eventTypeService as EventTypeService,
    translationService as TranslateService
  );
}

describe(ValueSelectorComponent.name, () => {
  let component: ValueSelectorComponent;
  // abbreviated for clarity
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockTranslateGet = jest.fn().mockReturnValue(of());
    mockTranslationService = {
      get: mockTranslateGet
    } as unknown as TranslateService;

    getAllSpy = jest.fn();
    mockEventTypeService = {
      getAll: getAllSpy
    } as unknown as EventTypeService;
    
    // abbreviated for clarity
    component = instantiate({
      eventTypeService: mockEventTypeService,
      translationService: mockTranslationService
    });
  });
```

But am struggling to get code coverage on () and ValueSelectorComponent of the `useExisting`.
Our tests are using JEST. The only solutions I've found involve TestBed, which we don't use. **How do I get coverage for that line?**

Answer (score 0):

Providers are part of Angular's DI system.

If you want to leverage them, you'll have a use that DI system. This where the `TestBed` comes to play:

```
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ ValueSelectorComponent ]
    });
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance
  });
```

Comment: I get that providers are Angular's DI, but we've got providers on all our other components and haven't needed to use TestBed for our unit tests on those. So why does the addition of forwardRef change the need for it here? Coverage was fine on this component until we had to add that.